# im getting an error type observer could not be resolved when observer is a class

Tags: c++, observer-pattern, nios

I am having an issue using pre-written obvserver design pattern code for C++. In the attach method, it is saying type Observer cannot be resolved when I have it declared as a class. Can anyone please help me trouble shoot this? I am also having another issue with views.push_back in this method. It is throwing an error "Invalid arguments, candidates are void push_back(Observer * const &)". I am new to C++ and don't quite understand these errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Subject {
    // 1. "independent" functionality
    vector < class Observer * > views; // 3. Coupled only to "interface"
    int value;
  public:
    void attach(Observer *obs) {
        views.push_back(obs);
    }
    void setVal(int val) {
        value = val;
        notify();
    }
    int getVal() {
        return value;
    }
    void notify();
};

class Observer {
    // 2. "dependent" functionality
    Subject *model;
    int denom;
  public:
    Observer(Subject *mod, int div) {
        model = mod;
        denom = div;
        // 4. Observers register themselves with the Subject
        model->attach(this);
    }
    virtual void update() = 0;
  protected:
    Subject *getSubject() {
        return model;
    }
    int getDivisor() {
        return denom;
    }
};

void Subject::notify() {
  // 5. Publisher broadcasts
  for (int i = 0; i < views.size(); i++)
    views[i]->update();
}

class DivObserver: public Observer {
  public:
    DivObserver(Subject *mod, int div): Observer(mod, div){}
    void update() {
        // 6. "Pull" information of interest
        int v = getSubject()->getVal(), d = getDivisor();
        cout << v << " div " << d << " is " << v / d << '\n';
    }
};

class ModObserver: public Observer {
  public:
    ModObserver(Subject *mod, int div): Observer(mod, div){}
    void update() {
        int v = getSubject()->getVal(), d = getDivisor();
        cout << v << " mod " << d << " is " << v % d << '\n';
    }
};
```

Comment: You may want to add a forward reference for `Observer` above `class Subject` definition.

Comment: what does that mean? sorry im relatively new to this

Comment: if i switch them around then I just get the same thing in Observer with Subject. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: a forward declaration is simply the line `class Observer;` placed above the `class Subject { ... ` definition.  This essentially tells the compiler to treat `Observer` as a class type ... the compiler won't know the size of the type or be able to access members of it yet (until it sees the definition of the class), but it will know the size of a pointer to the Observer class.  So you can define a vector that holds `Observer *` without the full Observer class definition.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the order in which you declared your classes. Class `Subject` uses class `Observer` but `Observer` was declared afterwards, so when the compiler tries to compile `Subject` is doesn't know what `Observer` is. However since `Subject` also uses `Observer` you can't just switch the order of declaration around.

The answer to this puzzle is to *forward declare* class `Observer` so at least the compiler knows that `Observer` is a class, even if it doesn't know much about it. Add `class Observer;` before your `class Subject` definition.
You can also remove the word `class` from your vector declaration.

```
class Observer;

class Subject {
    // 1. "independent" functionality
    vector < Observer * > views; // 3. Coupled only to "interface"
    ...
```